# Move category in back-offce

Tags: magento

Magento runs in closed loop when I want to move category in a other category in back-office.  Would somebody among them has an idea about the problem ?

PS: I have +6000 categorys

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by a "closed loop", but I'm going to guess that the reason for your problem is the number of categories you have. Magento often runs additional code as bookkeeping when doing things such as moving a category. You've probably run afoul of those routines (which can be computationally expensive).

As a suggestion, there is rarely a good reason to have so many categories. Try to make better use of attributes and layered navigation and you can probably bring that number significantly down. If you need a more concrete example, please give a little more detail about your categories and I'll do my best to help.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe